# how to use yield to return the value in a function?

Tags: node.js

I want get the returned value from function selectpro, but the value always gets null.

This is the function selectpro:

```
exports.selectpro = function(){
    var sql = "SELECT DISTINCT projectname FROM invoketable";
    var projectname;
    client.query(sql,function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err;
        projectname = result;

        console.log('select projectname from db');
        //console.log(projectname); //undefined
        //return projectname;  
    });
console.log(projectname); //undefined
return projectname;  
}
```

when to call the function selectpro:

```
var mysqlinsertp = require('./public/mysqloperate.js');

route.get('/readproject',function *(next){
    var dataprodect = mysqlinsertp.selectpro();
    this.body={status:200,ok:true,data:dataprodect};
    console.log(this.body);
});
```

I get the return is undefined. I tried to use 'yield' but when I use mysqlinsertp.selectpro().next() to call the function, it returns 'next() is not defined'.

Comment: Where r u calling var result = xx.selectpro()??

Comment: @Subburaj    I call the function in the file named  routes.js and `exports.selectpro = function(){}` defined in the file named readdb.js

Comment: what does this line: `console.log(projectname);` show you?

Comment: @AlexD  it showes undined

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your issue is timing the result.

You run `client.query`, which does the query and when its done, it will go to the callback function

```
function(err,result){
    if(err) throw err;
    projectname = result;

    console.log('select projectname from db');
});
```

So the lines

```
console.log(projectname);
return projectname;
```

Are misplaced there.

Your choices are adding a callback function or using a Promise.

**Callback function:**

```
exports.selectpro = function(cb){
    var sql = "SELECT DISTINCT projectname FROM invoketable";
    var projectname;
    client.query(sql,function(err,result) {
        if(err) { 
            cb(err, null);
        } else {
            projectname = result;

            console.log('select projectname from db');
            cb(null, projectname);
        }
    });
};
```

And then call it like this:

```
var result;
xx.selectpro(function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else result = res;
});
```

**Or using a Promise:**

```
exports.selectpro = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var sql = "SELECT DISTINCT projectname FROM invoketable";
        var projectname;
        client.query(sql,function(err,result){
            if(err) { 
                reject(err); 
            } else {
                projectname = result;

                console.log('select projectname from db');
                resolve(projectname);
            }
        });
    });

};
```

And then call it using:

```
var result;
xx.selectpro.then(function(res) {
    result = res;
});
```

Comment: thank you so much. can it  use generator in this situation if not why

Comment: What do you mean by generator?

Comment: yeah generator and yield

Comment: You shouldn't `throw` when you're using callbacks; just pass back the error. Also, you should return after rejecting.

Comment: when I use `var result;
xx.selectpro.then(function(res) {
    result = res;
});` It showes xx.selectpro.then is not a function